# Visual Studio Code + Internet Explorer: Is it possible to debug TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, internet-explorer, visual-studio-code

I can see that there are extensions for Visual Studio Code to debug JavaScript\TypeScript in [Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome). [Edge](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-edge) and [iOS Safari](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-ios-web).

But I need to debug TypeScript specifically in Internet Explorer for some reason.

Is there anything allowing to debug TypeScript in Internet Explorer from Visual Studio Code?

Comment: This is possible in full Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: @Misaz: Yes, thank you! But unfortunately full VS IDE can't be used to debug TypeScript in an Angular CLI app when you host it on Webpack server. This is exactly why I'm forced to use some other debugger rather than fulll VS IDE, though my project is developed using it in the first place.